# Restore Gmail Archive button

Tags: gmail

I have several emails labeled for follow up and am now ready to "delete" them from the label. I'd like to archive them, but no longer have an archive option, only delete. I did have an archive option up until recently, but now only have a delete option? How can I restore the archive option?

Comment: can you put up a screenshot of what you see?

Answer (score 1):

The archive button is used to remove the INBOX label from a message.

If you are looking at a bunch of messages by clicking on the label, you will not see the archive button. If you click on a message it may appear under the more button/menu.

If one or more messages still has the inbox label the more menu will contain the archive command. If the selected messages don't have the inbox label, the archive command will not be in the list. This make sense.

If you want to remove a label you can do so by clicking opening a message and clicking the small X next to the appropriate label. Or by selecting one or more messages and using the label button to changes the labels for the message. The confusing thing is that if you are looking in the "folder view" of the label you will not see the label of interest next to each message.